# How can I do a dynamic url that doesn't raise a 404 error if I click twice on the navbar the same button?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am currently working on my first web design and I'm experiencing some trouble with my url. What I'm trying to do is a navbar that when you click on the button, redirects you to a page. However, if I click twice on the navbar button, it raises a problem because the program is still reading the other url. Here's some photos so you can understand.
[[image]When I click on the translator button, the url adds translator.

[image]
Now If I click another time in the translator button, it raises a 404 error.

[image]
Now If I click on the home button, I still have the translator/ in the url, so it raises another 404 error.

My question is, how can I do a dynamic url so that when I click on another button, it doesn't appear a 404 error and redirects me to that page.

Here's the code of the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" style='background-color: snow;'>
    <div class = 'container'>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="{% static ''%}" width="70" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">

      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href='home'>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="translator">Translator</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" >Process</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

The generic urls.py navbar

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from translator.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('translator/', include('translator.urls')),
    path('', home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And the translator urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import translator_view 


app_name = 'translator'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', translator_view, name='translator'),
    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a builtin template tag: **[url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)**

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters.

So for any patterns located in your main project's `urls.py`, you can reverse them by using their pattern names, for example:

**urls.py**:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]
```

**.html**:

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a> {# outputs <a href="/">Home</a> #}
```

#### Note

If you have per app urls, like your **translator.urls**, you need to provide the app a namespace when you include it's urls, for example:

**urls.py**:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('translator/', include(('translator.urls', 'translator'), namespace='translator'))
]
```

**translator.urls.py**:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', translator_view, name='index'),
]
```

**.html**:

```
<a href="{% url 'translator:index' %}">Translator</a> {# outputs <a href="/translator/">Translator</a> #}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need pass your url names like this:

```
     <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href='{% url 'home' %}'>Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'translator:translator' %}">Translator</a>
      </li>


# urls.py

app_name = 'translator'
urlpatterns = [
path('', translator_view, name='translator', namespace='translator'),
```

]

Comment: I've tried that and it raises me this error: Reverse for 'translator' not found. 'translator' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: yeah you have to pass your app name before that i will edit my answer